# zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use, when running multiprocessing with multiple notebooks using papermill

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, pyzmq, papermill

I am using the papermill library to run multiple notebooks using multiprocessing simultaneously.

This is occurring on Python 3.6.6, Red Hat 4.8.2-15 within a Docker container.

However when I run the python script, about 5% of my notebooks do not work immediately (No Jupyter Notebook cells run) due to me receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-124>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 469, in initialize
    self.init_sockets()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 238, in init_sockets
    self.shell_port = self._bind_socket(self.shell_socket, self.shell_port)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 180, in _bind_socket
    s.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (self.ip, port))
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 547, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use
```

along with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 77, in run_papermill
    pm.execute_notebook(notebook, output_path, parameters=config)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/execute.py", line 104, in execute_notebook
    **engine_kwargs
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 49, in execute_notebook_with_engine
    return self.get_engine(engine_name).execute_notebook(nb, kernel_name, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 304, in execute_notebook
    nb = cls.execute_managed_notebook(nb_man, kernel_name, log_output=log_output, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 372, in execute_managed_notebook
    preprocessor.preprocess(nb_man, safe_kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/papermill/preprocess.py", line 20, in preprocess
    with self.setup_preprocessor(nb_man.nb, resources, km=km):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 345, in setup_preprocessor
    self.km, self.kc = self.start_new_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 296, in start_new_kernel
    kc.wait_for_ready(timeout=self.startup_timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/blocking/client.py", line 104, in wait_for_ready
    raise RuntimeError('Kernel died before replying to kernel_info')
RuntimeError: Kernel died before replying to kernel_info
```

Please help me with this problem, as I have scoured the web trying different solutions, none that have worked for my case so far.

This error rate of 5% occurs regardless of the number of notebooks I run simultaneously or the number of cores on my computer which makes it extra curious.

I have tried changing the start method and updating the libraries but to no avail.

The version of my libraries are:

```
papermill==1.2.1
ipython==7.14.0
jupyter-client==6.1.3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear problem attribution points towards ZeroMQ unable to successfully **`.bind()`**.

The error message : *`zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use`* is easier to explain. Whereas ZeroMQ AccessPoint-s can, for obvious reasons freely try to `.connect()` to many counterparts, yet one and only one can **`.bind()`** onto a particular Transport Class' Address Target.

There are three potential reasons for this happening:

**1 )** an accidental calling some code (without knowing internal details)
via **`{ multiprocessing.Process | joblib.Parallel | Docker-wrapped | ... }`**-spawned replicas, which each tries to acquire an ownership of some ZeroMQ Transport Class address, which will for obvious reasons fail to succeed for any attempt after a first one succeeded.

**2 )** a rather fatal situation, where some "previously"-run process did not manage to release such Transport Class specific address for further use ( do not remember that ZeroMQ might be just one of more other interested candidates - a Configuration Management flaw ), or in such cases, where previous runs failed to gracefully terminate such resource usage and left remained a **`Context()`**-instance still waiting ( infinitely in some cases till an O/S reboot ) listening for something, that will never happen.

**3 )** an indeed bad engineering practice in module software design, not to handle the ZeroMQ API documented **`EADDRINUSE`** error / exception less brutally than to just crash the whole circus (at all associated costs of that)

---

The other error message : *`RuntimeError: Kernel died before replying to kernel_info`* related to a state, that the notebook's kernel was trying so long to establish all internal connections with its own components ( pool-peers ) that it took waiting longer than a configured or hardcoded timeout and the kernel-process simply stopped waiting any more and threw itself into an otherwise unhandled exception you observed and reported.

### Solution

Check for any hanging address-owners first, reboot all nodes if in doubts on this, next verify there are no colliding attempts "hidden" inside your own code /  `{ multiprocessing.Process() | joblib.Parallel() | ... the likes }`-calls, that after distributed may try to `.bind()` onto the same target. If none of these steps salvage the trouble within your domain of control, ask the modules' used Support, to analyze and help you refactor & validate your still colliding use-case.